# calling methods, which one is better?

Tags: jquery, methods, click

I'm aware both these examples do the same thing, but are their any hidden differences? Is one faster than the other? Is it just a preferance?

```
$('#div1').on('click', function() {
$('#div2').toggle();
});



$('#div1').click(function() {
$('#div2').toggle();
});
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no difference in performance. Second one is just short hand for writing first one.

Answer (score 0):

`As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.`:http://api.jquery.com/bind/, http://api.jquery.com/on/

Also the the answer from this stackoverflow: [Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)